JSONObject["metaData"] is not a string (class org.json.JSONObject). after upgrading from Java 11 to Java 17
I've recently upgraded from Java 11 to Java 17. After this upgrade, I started getting the above issue, I don't face this issue with JDK 11.
The JSON string that causes the issue contains nested JSON metadata.
My code:
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String content = mapper.writeValueAsString(dataVirtualizationResource);

ClientBuilder clientBuilder = getClientBuilder();
client = clientBuilder.executorService(executorService).build();
Builder builder = getRequestBuilder(client, relativeURL);

Response response = builder.accept(responseType).put(Entity.entity(content, requestType));
if (response.getStatus() != OK) {
    throw new CliRESTException("Unable to perform PUT request: " + 
        response.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase(),
        Status.fromStatusCode(response.getStatus()), 
        response.readEntity(String.class));
}

return response.readEntity(String.class);

private ClientBuilder getClientBuilder() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    ClientBuilder clientBuilder = ResteasyClientBuilder.newBuilder();
    if (sslContextFactory.isTrustAllHosts()) {
        clientBuilder.hostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier());
    }
    if (useSSL) {
        clientBuilder.sslContext(sslContextFactory.create());
    }
    return clientBuilder;
}

private Builder getRequestBuilder(Client client, String relativeUrl) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    String urlStr = url.toString() + relativeUrl;
    WebTarget target = client.target(urlStr);

    Builder builder = target.request();
    builder.header("Authorization", authString);
    if (session != null) {
        builder.cookie(SESSION_COOKIE, session);
    }
    return builder;
}

Class of the object "dataVirtualizationResource":
public class DataVirtualizationResource {
    public class MetaDataResource{  
        public static class MetadataResourceInfo{    
        private ResourceType resourceType;    
        private String resourceName;    
        private String resourceContentAsJSON;  
        public String getResourceContentAsJSON(){      
            return resourceContentAsJSON;    
        }    
        public void setResourceContentAsJSON(String resourceContentAsJSON){      
            this.resourceContentAsJSON = resourceContentAsJSON;    
        }    
        public String getResourceName(){      
            return resourceName;   
        }    
        public void setResourceName(String resourceName){      
            this.resourceName = resourceName;    
        }    
        public ResourceType getResourceType(){      
            return resourceType;    
        }    
        public void setResourceType(ResourceType resourceType){      
            this.resourceType = resourceType;    
        }  
    }  
    private MetadataResourceInfo resource;  
    private List<MetadataResourceInfo> dependentResources;  
    public MetadataResourceInfo getResource(){
        return resource;  
    }  
    public void setResource(MetadataResourceInfo resource){    
        this.resource = resource;  
    }
    public List<MetadataResourceInfo> getDependentResources(){    
        return dependentResources;  
    }  
    public void setDependentResources(List<MetadataResourceInfo> dependentResources){
        this.dependentResources = dependentResources;  
    }
}

The definition of the outer class begins at the line private MetadataResourceInfo resource;. Apart from the nested class, it contains two data members i.e. 'resource' and 'dependentResources' and their getters and setters.
I get the issue in the response, the status is "OK" but when the response object is read using the readEntity(String.class), the message is read as JSONObject["metaData"] is not a string (class org.json.JSONObject)..
pom.xml file used in the project:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.pb.spectrum</groupId>
    <artifactId>spectrum-cli</artifactId>
    <version>0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.pb.spectrum.cli</groupId>
  <artifactId>spectrum-cli-runtime</artifactId>
  <name>Spectrum - Command Line Interface Runtime</name>
  <properties>
    <spring.shell.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring.shell.version>
    <spectrum.version>${project.version}</spectrum.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-shell</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.shell.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.pb.spectrum.platformsdk.serverapi</groupId>
      <artifactId>spectrum-api-cli</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.pb.spectrum.platformsdk.serverapi</groupId>
      <artifactId>spectrum-api-metadata</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.pb.spectrum.platform.server.config</groupId>
      <artifactId>spectrum-server-config-api</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.pb.spectrum.metadata-insights.federation</groupId>
      <artifactId>logicalmodel-api</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.precisely.spectrum.contextgraph.server.common.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>spectrum-contextgraph-server-common-api</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- executors -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.pb.spectrum.platform.executors</groupId>
      <artifactId>jobexecutor</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.pb.spectrum.platform.executors</groupId>
      <artifactId>pflowexecutor</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!--third party -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>${json.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
      <version>4.6.1.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
      <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/version.txt</include>
          <include>**/display-version.txt</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/version.txt</exclude>
          <exclude>**/display-version.txt</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <!-- make the jar executable by adding a Main-Class to the manifest -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>org.springframework.shell.Bootstrap</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>com.pb.spectrum.platform.executors:jobexecutor</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>org/slf4j/**</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>com.pb.spectrum.platform.executors:pflowexecutor</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>org/slf4j/**</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
                <filter>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>org/dom4j/**</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <artifactSet>
                <excludes>
<!--                   <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude> -->
                </excludes>
              </artifactSet>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <argLine>
         --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
        </argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

A sample JSON string that gives the error:
{
  "resource": {
    "resourceType": "PhysicalModel",

    "resourceName": "TestModel",

    "resourceContentAsJSON": "{\"name\":\"TestModel\",\"sourceInfo\":{\"dataSourceType\":\"Flat File\",\"dataSourceName\":\"TestConnection\"},\"metaData\":{\"tableMetadata\":{\"input10\":{\"entityItemMetadata\":{\"nameInSource\":\"input10\",\"supportsUpdate\":null,\"entityColumns\":[{\"columnName\":\"AddressLine1\",\"nativeType\":\"STRING\",\"runtimeType\":\"string\",\"spectrumType\":\"string\",\"updatable\":true,\"searchable\":true,\"nameInSource\":\"AddressLine1\",\"length\":null,\"scale\":null,\"precision\":null,\"autoIncremented\":null,\"currency\":null,\"nullType\":null,\"defaultValue\":null,\"annotations\":null,\"radix\":null,\"charOctetLength\":null,\"columnProperties\":null,\"name\":\"AddressLine1\",\"primaryKey\":false},{\"columnName\":\"City\",\"nativeType\":\"STRING\",\"runtimeType\":\"string\",\"spectrumType\":\"string\",\"updatable\":true,\"searchable\":true,\"nameInSource\":\"City\",\"length\":null,\"scale\":null,\"precision\":null,\"autoIncremented\":null,\"currency\":null,\"nullType\":null,\"defaultValue\":null,\"annotations\":null,\"radix\":null,\"charOctetLength\":null,\"columnProperties\":null,\"name\":\"City\",\"primaryKey\":false},{\"columnName\":\"StateProvince\",\"nativeType\":\"STRING\",\"runtimeType\":\"string\",\"spectrumType\":\"string\",\"updatable\":true,\"searchable\":true,\"nameInSource\":\"StateProvince\",\"length\":null,\"scale\":null,\"precision\":null,\"autoIncremented\":null,\"currency\":null,\"nullType\":null,\"defaultValue\":null,\"annotations\":null,\"radix\":null,\"charOctetLength\":null,\"columnProperties\":null,\"name\":\"StateProvince\",\"primaryKey\":false},{\"columnName\":\"PostalCode\",\"nativeType\":\"STRING\",\"runtimeType\":\"string\",\"spectrumType\":\"string\",\"updatable\":true,\"searchable\":true,\"nameInSource\":\"PostalCode\",\"length\":null,\"scale\":null,\"precision\":null,\"autoIncremented\":null,\"currency\":null,\"nullType\":null,\"defaultValue\":null,\"annotations\":null,\"radix\":null,\"charOctetLength\":null,\"columnProperties\":null,\"name\":\"PostalCode\",\"primaryKey\":false},{\"columnName\":\"Country\",\"nativeType\":\"STRING\",\"runtimeType\":\"string\",\"spectrumType\":\"string\",\"updatable\":true,\"searchable\":true,\"nameInSource\":\"Country\",\"length\":null,\"scale\":null,\"precision\":null,\"autoIncremented\":null,\"currency\":null,\"nullType\":null,\"defaultValue\":null,\"annotations\":null,\"radix\":null,\"charOctetLength\":null,\"columnProperties\":null,\"name\":\"Country\",\"primaryKey\":false}],\"tableProperties\":null,\"primaryKey\":null,\"foreignKeys\":[],\"additionalDisplayProperties\":null,\"name\":\"input10\"},\"entityProperties\":null}},\"joinInfoList\":[],\"systemGenerated\":false}",


    "metaDataAsJSON": "{\"tableMetadata\":{\"input10\":{\"entityItemMetadata\":{\"nameInSource\":\"input10\",\"supportsUpdate\":null,\"entityColumns\":[{\"columnName\":\"AddressLine1\",\"nativeType\":\"STRING\",\"runtimeType\":\"string\",\"spectrumType\":\"string\",\"updatable\":true,\"searchable\":true,\"nameInSource\":\"AddressLine1\",\"length\":null,\"scale\":null,\"precision\":null,\"autoIncremented\":null,\"currency\":null,\"nullType\":null,\"defaultValue\":null,\"annotations\":null,\"radix\":null,\"charOctetLength\":null,\"columnProperties\":null,\"name\":\"AddressLine1\",\"primaryKey\":false},{\"columnName\":\"City\",\"nativeType\":\"STRING\",\"runtimeType\":\"string\",\"spectrumType\":\"string\",\"updatable\":true,\"searchable\":true,\"nameInSource\":\"City\",\"length\":null,\"scale\":null,\"precision\":null,\"autoIncremented\":null,\"currency\":null,\"nullType\":null,\"defaultValue\":null,\"annotations\":null,\"radix\":null,\"charOctetLength\":null,\"columnProperties\":null,\"name\":\"City\",\"primaryKey\":false},{\"columnName\":\"StateProvince\",\"nativeType\":\"STRING\",\"runtimeType\":\"string\",\"spectrumType\":\"string\",\"updatable\":true,\"searchable\":true,\"nameInSource\":\"StateProvince\",\"length\":null,\"scale\":null,\"precision\":null,\"autoIncremented\":null,\"currency\":null,\"nullType\":null,\"defaultValue\":null,\"annotations\":null,\"radix\":null,\"charOctetLength\":null,\"columnProperties\":null,\"name\":\"StateProvince\",\"primaryKey\":false},{\"columnName\":\"PostalCode\",\"nativeType\":\"STRING\",\"runtimeType\":\"string\",\"spectrumType\":\"string\",\"updatable\":true,\"searchable\":true,\"nameInSource\":\"PostalCode\",\"length\":null,\"scale\":null,\"precision\":null,\"autoIncremented\":null,\"currency\":null,\"nullType\":null,\"defaultValue\":null,\"annotations\":null,\"radix\":null,\"charOctetLength\":null,\"columnProperties\":null,\"name\":\"PostalCode\",\"primaryKey\":false},{\"columnName\":\"Country\",\"nativeType\":\"STRING\",\"runtimeType\":\"string\",\"spectrumType\":\"string\",\"updatable\":true,\"searchable\":true,\"nameInSource\":\"Country\",\"length\":null,\"scale\":null,\"precision\":null,\"autoIncremented\":null,\"currency\":null,\"nullType\":null,\"defaultValue\":null,\"annotations\":null,\"radix\":null,\"charOctetLength\":null,\"columnProperties\":null,\"name\":\"Country\",\"primaryKey\":false}],\"tableProperties\":null,\"primaryKey\":null,\"foreignKeys\":[],\"additionalDisplayProperties\":null,\"name\":\"input10\"},\"entityProperties\":null}},\"joinInfoList\":[],\"systemGenerated\":false}",


    "sourceInfoAsJSON": "{\"dataSourceType\":\"Flat File\",\"dataSourceName\":\"TestConnection\"}",


    "tableInfo": [
      {
        "tableName": "input10",
        "fullTableName": "input10",
        "baseViewName": "TestModel",
        "tableId": null,
        "displayOptions": null,
        "dataSourceConnectionName": null
      }
    ],


    "selected": false
  },
  "dependentResources": []
}

What I'm getting in the Response object:
Error: Unable to import resource: TestModel of type: physicalModel since JSONObject\["metaData"\] is not a string (class org.json.JSONObject).

I've tried upgrading JAX-RS and JBOSS. I can't modify the JSON as this represents a file and gets created while exporting the file. Moreover, the JSON was working before and there may be many nested JSON for different files. I tried many different things suggested by ChatGPT but to no avail.

What version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you using? It's hard to tell what's happening, but it looks like a mix of different JSON marshallers.

I'm using the JBoss Resteasy dependencies and the version is 4.6.1.Final. The JSON version is 20240303.

What container are you running in? RESTEasy only supports Jakarta JSON Binding and Jackson by default. If you want to use a different JSON library you'd need to write your own provider.

I am using Jackson to create the JSON string. ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String content = mapper.writeValueAsString(dataVirtualizationResource);

org.json.JSONObject is not a Jackson type though and that's what's in the error. Do you have some kind of reproducer by chance? I understand it might not be that simple to have a reproducer for it :)

I will try to create a sample project where this can be replicated. However, I was wondering how this was working until Java 11?

It's hard to say really. You'd want to make sure you're using the same versions of RESTEasy for each dependency. You'd need to find out where and why the org.json.JSONObject is coming from too.

I will check for the RESTEasy version. The “metadata” which is being read as a JSON object is a nested JSON. But the thing is what it was working fine until Java 11. Is it because I have upgraded to Java 11?
If yes, how can I resolve the issue in that case?

It's hard to say TBH. It could have to do with the order in which libraries are loaded in your class path. I would look to see if you've got org.json:json somewhere in your dependency tree and try to exclude that.

I had org.json:json as a transitive dependency with the scope as 'complie'. I tried by removing the transitive dependency but that didn't resolve the issue.

Do you see the same error message or something different? If you're seeing the same error message then it seems the library is still being included in your deployment.
